# Please help me understand this css issue

Tags: css

I have the below code.The third div overlaps with the second one.I have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v6E9a/4/ .Can someone please tell me how I can line these div's correctly.I have to use position:absolute as it supports some functionality.

```
  <div id="s4-workspace" style="width: 1920px; height: 748px; overflow:scroll">
    <div id="s4-bodyContainer" style="position:relative">

        <div class="headerSection" style="position:relative ;border : 3px solid red">
            <div class="globalHeader">
                header
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="contentRow" style="position:relative">
                <div class="fixedWidthMain" style="position:relative">

                    <div class="fixedWidthMain" style="position:absolute ;border:3px solid blue">
                        main data
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--PAGE FOOTER SECTION-->
    <div class="pageFooterSection" style="clear: both;position:relative ;border:3px solid green">
        footer
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you want the div's to display?

Comment: *how I can line these div's correctly*? if you need to line them up, so why do you need to set `absolute` for the second? doing so will take it out of the current document flow.

Comment: this html is very simplified version of my issue.There is a product which generates this html and which generates some popups based on this absolute position so I need to keep it.

Comment: The problem is that positioning the div absolutely removes it from the document flow so the other divs aren't aware of it. So you'll either need to hard code some value to deal with the movement, or use JavaScript to read its size and position and change the other divs accordingly.

Comment: does on the middle div need to have position absolute?

Comment: yes that's the requirement

Comment: is the middle div subject to change height? or is it going to stay a certain height?

Comment: Can you show us a picture of what you want? Clarifying your code might help too.

Comment: I have updated the code to give a more realistic picture.Also the main content div has dynamic content so i cannot use fixed height in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to account for the height of the first `<div>` by positioning the second one from the top the same height as the first div.

[image]

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6E9a/5/)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Is this what you want?</strike>

```
<div style="border: 3px solid red">
    1
</div>
<div style="border: 3px solid green; position: absolute">
    2
</div>
<div style="border: 3px solid blue; margin-left: 14px;">
    3
</div>
```

### Result

[image]

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jsve/F3sNJ/2/)**

To make it work with different font sizes: use `display: inline;`:

```
<div style="border : 3px solid red; font-size: 40px;">
    1 lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
<div style="border : 3px solid green; font-size: 40px; display: inline;">
    2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
<div style="border : 3px solid blue; display:inline; font-size: 40px;">
    3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```

### Result

[image]

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsve/F3sNJ/3/)**

Comment: And if the font face or size changes, or the content changes, then what?

Comment: _"I have to use position:absolute as it supports some functionality."_

Comment: I need the div to line up normally while supporting absolute in the middle div.